# How do I convert a string to integer

Tags: mysql

How do I convert a string to integer?

I'd like to convert the data of column `value_int` in table `users` from string to integer.

I've searched and tried `CONVERT` and `CAST`.

Comment: What went wrong when you tried `CAST`? It's correct.

Comment: What **specifically** have you tried, and how **specifically** did it not work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The valid type for the result can be one of the following values:

```
BINARY[(N)]
CHAR[(N)]
DATE
DATETIME
DECIMAL[(M[,D])]
SIGNED [INTEGER]
TIME
UNSIGNED [INTEGER]
```

Therefore, you should use:

```
SELECT CAST(value_int AS UNSIGNED) FROM users
```

see  [mysql website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) for more details